# Onclick event with PHP, ajax and jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to use an `onclick` event with PHP in order to accomplish the following.  I would like to use ajax to avoid the page being refreshed. I want to create buttons on event click.

I don't know how to join the div buttons with the ajax result.

Here is my PHP file: `Button.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dymanic Buttons</title>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src ="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>    
        <script type= "text/javascript" src ="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="Add_Button" value="Add Button"</>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="Modify_Button" value="Modify    Button"</>
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="Delete_Button" value="Delete    Button"</>
        </div>
```

`test.js` contains this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.button').click(function () {
        var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();

        var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
            data = {
                'action': clickBtnValue
            };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

            alert("action performed successfully");

        });
    });

});
```

And the other php that is `ajax.php`

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['action'])){
  switch($_POST['action']){
      case 'Add_Button':
  Add_Button();
  break;
  }

}
function Add_Button(){
    echo '<input type="submit" class="button" name="Test_Button" value ="Test Button"</>';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: in ajax.php change case 'Add_Button':  => 'Add Button':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the result of request to your div with this:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

   $("div").append(response);
   alert("action performed successfully");

});
```

Note the value of your button is "Add Button", not "Add_Button"

Comment: If a want to use this with specific div, may I can add another name and an ID to the div? for example:                                                                                           $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {

   $("result").append(response);
   alert("action performed successfully");

});                                                                                                                  <div class ="result"></div>

Comment: It is recommended so you have a target div instead of all divs.

Comment: Exactly what I want however, how I can tell to my jQuery code that I want to use this for an specific div?

Comment: `$("div#my_id").append(response); ` If you have a div with the id my_id or `$("div.my_class").append(response); ` If you have a div with the class my_class

Comment: it works, now im trying to look for a command that is capable to delete the button that the code create, any idea?

Comment: `$(".button[name='Delete_Button']").click(function () { $(".button[name='Test_Button']").remove(); });`

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `<input>`'s value, instead of it's name which you set it as.

Change your `clickBtnValue` to this:

```
var clickBtnValue = $(this).attr('name');
```

<sup>*Since it has `Add_Button`/`Modify_Button`/etc.*</sup>

To append the new button to your div, start by giving it an `id`, so that we can continue to call it:

```
<div id="my-buttons">
```

Now in your `ajax` request, simply [`jQuery.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the html to the div:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    $('div#my-buttons').append(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make sure that each component of your code is working first. The problem may be in your AJAX call, it should be similar to the following:

```
/** AJAX Call Start **/
    // AJAX call to dict.php
    $.ajax({

        /** Call parameters **/
        url: "ajax.php", // URL for processing
        type: "POST", // POST method
        data: {'action': clickBtnValue}, // Data payload

        // Upon retrieving data successfully...
        success: function(data) {}
});
```

Also, make sure you are using the correct routing to your PHP file and that your PHP file is returning a valid response.

EDIT: As per the jQuery Docs, I am fairly certain that the problem is within your AJAX call, specifically your `$.post()` setup. Please refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for the proper setup is you want to keep your AJAX call structured as is instead of the way I suggested.

As per the jQuery Docs:

> ```
> $.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
>   $( ".result" ).html( data );
> });
> ```